# Prove $f(x)$ has three extremum points on $(-2\pi,2\pi)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Prove $f(x)$ has three extremum points on $(-2\pi,2\pi)$
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}, x \not= 0 $$
$$f(x) = 1, x = 0 $$
I calculated its derivative.
$$f'(x) = \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}, x \not= 0$$
$$f'(x) = 0, x = 0$$
I can see that $f'(x)$ has a solution for x = 0.
I am not sure how to solve for $x\not= 0$ though. I have tried this:
$$ \frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2} = 0 $$
Multiply both sides by $x^2$
$$ x\cos x - \sin x = 0 $$
Add $\sin x$ to both sides
$$ x\cos x = \sin x$$
Now divide both sides by $\cos x$
$$ x = \tan x $$
Did I do anything wrong? Can this equation be figured out without using any kind of graphing tool?

Comment: Now apply the inverse function, $x=k\pi+\arctan x$ has one solution for each $k$.

Comment: Nothing wrong so far. What's the difficulty in proceeding? You can't expect to solve that transcendental equation exactly. Why not solve with an accurate curve sketch with some simple analysis to back up your conclusions?

Comment: You can find the number of solutions to $x=\tan(x) $ though you probably can't find the solutions themselves analytically. You can see that $\tan(x) - x$ is strictly increasing hence you only have to look at $[-2\pi,-3\pi/2),(-3\pi/2,\pi],[-\pi,-\pi/2),(-\pi/2,0],[0,\pi/2),(\pi/2,\pi],[\pi,3\pi/2),(3\pi/2,2\pi]$

Comment: @N. F. Taussig The intervals are open, I edited the question.

Comment: You can first use Rolle's theorem to find that there are at least three roots. Then $\tan x$ is strictly increasing between $[-3 \pi/2, \pi/2), [-\pi/2, \pi/2), [\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$. For the intervals $[-2 \pi, -3 \pi/2)$ and $[2 \pi, 3 \pi/2)$, $\tan x$ is again strictly increasing, and the minimum value in those intervals is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)= x \cos x -\sin x.$

We have:

1. $g(0)=0.$
2. $g(2 \pi)=2 \pi$ and $g(\pi)= -  \pi$. By the intermediate value theorem, $g$ has a zero in $( \pi, 2 \pi).$
3. $g(-2 \pi)=-2 \pi$ and $g(- \pi)= \pi$. By the intermediate value theorem, $g$ has a zero in $( -2\pi, -\pi).$

So far, we have that $g$ has three zeros in $( -2 \pi, 2 \pi).$

Now it is your turn to show that $g$ has exactly three zeros in $( -2 \pi, 2 \pi).$

(Use $g'$ and look in which subintervalls of $( -2 \pi, 2 \pi)$ the function $g$ is increasing / decreasing.)

Answer (score 1):

What you did is very correct and there is no explicit solution to the equation.

Discarding the trivial case $x=0$, it is better to consider that you look for the zero's of
$$f(x)=x \cos (x)-\sin (x)$$ Now, consider a Taylor expansion close to $\frac {3 \pi} 2$ (remember the symmetry) to get
$$f(x)=1+\frac{3}{2} \pi  \left(x-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{3 \pi
   }{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(x-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3 \pi   }{2}\right)^4\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$x=\frac{3 \pi }{2}-\frac{2}{3 \pi }-\frac{16}{81 \pi ^3}-\frac{16}{243 \pi ^5}- \cdots$$ This truncated expansion would give $x=4.4936$ while the "exact" solution would be $4.4934$.

Just compute the value of the function at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$
f'(x)=\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}
$$
Therefore, $f(x)=0\implies|f'(x)|=\frac1{|x|}\ne0$.

$f$ has simple roots at $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, and $2\pi$. In between each pair of adjacent roots, $f$ has at least one local extremum. Thus, there are at least $3$ local extrema in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$.

$f'(x)=0\implies\tan(x)=x$ which happens once on $\left[-\frac{3\pi}2,-\pi\right]$, at $0$, and once on $\left[\pi,\frac{3\pi}2\right]$. Thus there are at most $3$ roots.