# How do I show that $x - \tan x$ has exactly 3 solutions on $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, roots

Is there an easy way to show this without graphing the function? I am really looking for how 12th grader you would solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave the original solution here, for anyone who wants to read it over quickly.

> Define $I_n:=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)+\pi n$. The function $f(x)=\tan x-x$ is
>   strictly increasing and continuous on $I_n$ with $f((-\pi/2+\pi n)^+)=-\infty,f((\pi/2+\pi n)^-)=\infty$. Hence $f$ has exactly one root
>   in $I_n$.
>
> Now, we have exactly three such intervals included in $(-2\pi,2\pi)$.
>   It remains only to prove that there are no roots on $(-2\pi,-3\pi/2)$
>   and $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$. For example, over $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$, since $f(x)$
>   is increasing we have:
>
> $$f(x)<f(2\pi)=-2\pi<0$$
>
> so no real roots over $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$. The case $(-2\pi,-3\pi/2)$ is
>   similar. In conclusion, there are exactly three real roots over
>   $(-2\pi,2\pi)$.

Now I'll try to explain it more clearly. We are asked to prove that the equation $\tan x = x$ has exactly three roots over $[-2\pi,2\pi]$. This is the same as saying the function

$$f:(-2\pi, 2\pi)\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=\tan x -x$$

has exactly three zeroes. However, the domain is not correct because $\tan$ is not defined at $k\frac{\pi}{2}, k\in \mathbb{Z}^*$. So, we should actually define $f$ as:

$$f:\left(-2\pi,-\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(-\frac{3\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right)\to \mathbb{R}$$

The intervals $\left(-\frac{3\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right), \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$ are the intervals I denoted by $I_n$ in the original solution. The function $\tan x$ is periodic with period $\pi$ so its behavior is the same over each of these intervals. So let's pick one of them, say $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$. I'll add a picture of the functions over $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$, so that it's easier to grasp the arguments.

[image]

With red, it's $\tan x$ and with green it's $f(x)=\tan x - x$.

Now, as you can see in the picture, the function $f$ is continuous over $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$, of course this is because both $\tan x$ and $x$ are continuous over $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$ and since $f$ is the difference of two continuous function, it is continuous. Also, from the picture, you can see that both functions are increasing. To support this, we can compute the first derivative: $(\tan x)'=\tan^2 x+1>0$ and $f'(x)=\tan^2x\geq 0$, so clearly they are both increasing.

Now, let's see from and toward what do they increase. For this, we must compute the limit to the right of the lower bound and the limit to the left of the upper bound. We have:

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^+} \tan x-\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}x=-\infty-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{3\pi}{2}^-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \frac{3\pi}{2}^-} \tan x-\lim_{x\to \frac{3\pi}{2}^-}x=\infty-\frac{3\pi}{2}=\infty$$

Now, since the function is continuous and increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, this means it covers all the possible values from $\mathbb{R}$ exactly once. That means, it intersects the $x$-axis exactly once over the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$, i.e. we have exactly one root over this interval (the $B$ point in the picture).

By exactly the same arguments, there is exactly one solution over $\left(-\frac{3\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and exactly one solution over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

So we have our three roots. It remains to prove that there are none other over the rest of $f$'s domain.

Let's take for example $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right)$.

[image]

By the same arguments as previously, $\tan x- x$ is increasing and continuous over $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}\right)$, which means it is increasing over $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right]$. Thus, for any $x\in \left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right)$, we have

$$f(x) < f(2\pi)=\tan 2\pi-2\pi=-2\pi < 0$$

This means $f(x)$ can't be zero for any $x\in \left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right)$ (since it is smaller than zero), which means no roots over this interval. You can also see in the picture that $f(x)$ is way below the $x-axis$. To be more specific, $f$'s root over the interval $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}\right)$ lies in the right half $\left(2\pi, \frac{5\pi}{2}\right)$.

So, we're good with the interval $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right)$, because we don't have any other roots here. For the interval $\left(-2\pi,-\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$ the argument is almost identical (you have $f(x) > f(-2\pi)=2\pi >0$), so no solutions there either.

In conclusion, there are exactly three roots over the interval $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$.

Comment: I don't understand a thing of what you had written. I am overwhelmed by a lot of answers on this site. Like were you really doing things like this in 12th grade?

Comment: @RaduGabriel, I don't know, we don't have a 12th grade over here. What specific step is overwhelming you?

Comment: 12th grade = last year of high school. Everything about your answer is overwhelming, I don't know, I am really disheartened right now, I always turn to this site as a last resort because of answers that are out of reach for me, like this one. I don't even know what $I_n$ is, or what the $:=$ sign means.

Comment: And I really appreciate you trying to help, you've helped me before with my math struggles just fine. I am just confused and sad right now, sorry for the rant.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, No problem. I'm here to help. I'll try to edit and explain more clearly.

Comment: Don't please. I will ask the question again tomorrow, more detailed too.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, I haven't struggled with maths in high school, nor am I now in college, but I have struggled with other subjects and I can understand you. So I will try to help you.

That being said, the question you asked is not trivial You need some calculus knowledge of how continuous functions behave and knowledge about $tan$ (that is periodic with period $pi$, that it's increasing over $(-pi/2, pi/2)$, that it goes to $infty$ when the argument approaches $pi/2$ from the left a.s.o.). I don't know what you're being taught at school, it would help if you would mention what you already know

Comment: I know the unit circle, how trig functions' graphs look like and understand what it means for a function to be continuous. I will ask the question again (right now), including every detail that I omitted. I took the question out of context, maybe it might have given some helpful information on how to solve the problem.

Comment: After writing for one hour I realized that I have asked this question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355050/prove-fx-has-three-extremum-points-on-2-pi-2-pi

Comment: I don't know how to put it. I have the knowledge to solve this type of problems, but for this one once I calculated $f'(x)$ and realized I can't find the solutions, I would've thought about getting information about $f'(x)$'s values by calculating its derivative, but I immediately thought why would I be able to find the solutions for $f''(x) =0$ when it only gets messier from here? Apparently, I didn't have to solve it, just consider some intervals and find the values at the end of them. I still have trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, the two questions ($\tan x = x$ vs $x\cos x=\sin x$) are similar, but essentially different because when you divide by $\cos x$ you introduce discontinuity points where $\cos $ has zeroes (at $k\pi/2$) and thus $\tan $ is undefined. So there is a different definition domain.

Out of the proofs there, I think Fred's is easiest (and similar to what I did here). Do you want me to explain it more clearly? Or do you want me to explain what I did above in easier terms? I would rather do the latter, because now that I read it again, I realize I can phrase it in easier terms.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, I edited to explain in more details. If there are other uncertainties about it, let me know.

Comment: I really appreciate your time, it is clear to me now. I have another question. When I rewrite $x\cos x -\sin x = 0 $ to become $\tan x - x = 0$, I realized their graphs (by using desmos) are not the same anymore despite having the same solutions. Why can we then 'analyze' the graph of this new rewritten function as if it was the same as the original one? I am asking because $\tan x - x$ is a LOT easier to differentiate than $\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2}$.

Comment: For example the derivative of $\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2}$ = $\frac{-\sin x}{x} - \frac{2x\cos x-\sin x}{x^3}$ while the derivative of $\tan x - x$ = $\tan^2 (x)$. I wouldn't even know how to tell if the first one is positive or negative at all, while $\tan^2 x$ is effortless.

Comment: @RaduGabriel, That's the point I was trying to make in an earlier comment. It's not the same function. $x\cos x-\sin x =0$ is not equivalent with $\tan x - x=0$ for any real number $x$ (we have some undefined points at $...,-\frac{3\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},..$). They are however (very) related questions because $\tan x-x=\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{\cos x}$. We can analyze this function because they have the same zeros ($tan x_0-x_0=0 \Leftrightarrow \sin x_0-x_0\cos x_0=0$).

Comment: @RaduGabriel, The derivative is easier to compute, because we ignore both $x^2$ in the denominator and then the $\cos x$ in $\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x}$. Since we are only intersted in zeroes, the denominator of these functions cannot be zero (it would be an undefined point of the function, not a root), so we can ignore the denominators.